# vimdiff with interactive shell

Tags: shell, vim

I have `shellcmdflag=-ic` in my .vimrc to make the shell interactive
(This was done to read the alias')

With this interactive option set, the shell command (run with ! in front)
will always make vim to go background as if `Ctrl-z` was pressed and I have to `fg` to bring back vim.

I am fine with having to `fg` to get vim back to front, but this interactive shell also broke `vimdiff`.

Whether I enter diff mode through `vimdiff` or `:difft`, I have to `fg` twice to get back to vim and it sometimes even crashes the whole konsole..

below is my `:version` from vim

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled May  4 2012 04:21:49)
Included patches: 1-429
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent +clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments +conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape
+dialog_con_gui +diff +digraphs +dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path +find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() +gettext -hangul_input +iconv +insert_expand +jumplist +keymap
+langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap +lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse +mouseshape +mouse_dec +mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse +mouse_xterm +mouse_urxvt
+multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg +path_extra +perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer +profile +python -python3 +quickfix +reltime +rightleft +ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent -sniff
+startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white +tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title +toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup +X11 -xfontset +xim +xsmp_interact +xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
 user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
  user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
 user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
  system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12     -g -O2 -fstack-protect or --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/usr/include/tcl8.5  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -Wl,-E  -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0   -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/
lib -llua5.1  -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl/5.14/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lcrypt -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -
Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions  -L/usr/lib -ltcl8.5 -ldl -lpthread -lieee -lm -lruby1.8 -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm  -L/usr/lib
```

Anyone had the same issue?

Comment: sorry I didn't realize that I missed those out..

OS : Linux kubuntu 3.2.0-27-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 6 14:25:57 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Shell : bash

Comment: Is it the parent shell that's crashing or the Konsole app? If it's Konsole you might want to file a bug with KDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps instead of setting the Vim subshell to interactive mode to get your aliases, check for the `$VIM` environment variable in your `.bashrc`:

```
if [[ $- = *i* || ! -z "$VIM" ]]; then
  # alias ll=...
fi
```

You'll need to [explicitly tell bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) to source your `.bashrc` since it doesn't source anything when in non-login, non-interactive mode (`-c`). Also, [alias expansion needs enabling](http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/nix/shell/gsh05-ShBash/ar01s13.html). In your `.vimrc` add:

```
let $BASH_ENV = '~/.bashrc'
set shellcmdflag=-O\ expand_aliases\ -c
```

Comment: I've tried putting your lines into my `.bashrc` and setting `shellcmdflag` to -c instead of -ic but the alias is not recognized from vim. What am I missing?

Comment: Ah, right. I forgot that bash doesn't source anything when `-c` is specified. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping me on this issue. I've changed my .bashrc and .vimrc to the following:
`.bashrc:
if [[ $- = *i* || ! -z "$VIM" ]]; then
    alias blahblah 
fi
  

.vimrc:
let $BASH_ENV = '~/.bashrc'
set shellcmdflag=-O\ expand_aliases\ -c
` and still no luck..

Comment: Try it out in a plain bash shell, without vim: `BASH_ENV='~/.bashrc' VIM=x bash -O expand_aliases -c 'alias foo'`, where `foo` is one of your aliases. It should print out the definition of the alias. (`alias foo='echo'`) If it doesn't, comment out things from your `.bashrc` until it does.

Comment: Thank you Wilbur for your help. I've tried what you've suggested and now I have what I wanted. There was `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` on the top of my .bashrc which I think came default with Kubuntu 12.04.. I've moved the aliases to above that return line and they are now recognized properly.
I didn't have to put `if [[ $- = *i* || -z "$VIM" ]]` since normal aliasing still worked..

Comment: Excellent! Yes, the `if $-…` is probably over-cautious.